# Initial Value Problem of a Differential Equation Involving a Step Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, greens-function

We were given the problem

$$y'+ay=h_1 \quad y(0)=0$$
$$h_1(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if  } 0 < x \leq 1  \\
0, & \text{if } x> 1
\end{cases}$$

and tasked with finding the function $y$. We were told that one method we may use involves Green's Function, but we are allowed to use whatever method we choose.

**What I have attempted**

From having already calculated the Laplace transformation of $h_1$ previously to be $H(x)=\frac{1-e^{-s}}{s}$, I then set
$$ \mathscr{L}[y](s)=Y(s)$$
$$ \mathscr{L}[y'](s)=sY(s)$$
giving me the transformed problem:
$$sY(s)+aY(s)=\frac{1-e^{-s}}{s}$$
$$Y(s)=\frac{1-e^{-s}}{s(s+a)}$$
which looked really complicated to find the inverse of, so I decided there was probably an easier way.

I then tried to use Green's function (which I don't wholly understand):
$$Y(s)=G(s)H(s), \quad G(s)=\frac{1}{\chi}=\frac{1}{s+a}=\mathscr{L}[e^{-ax}](s)$$
$$\Rightarrow g(x)=e^{-ax} $$
$$y(x)=(g*h_1)(x)=\int_0^xg(x-\tau)h_1(\tau)d\tau=\int_0^xe^{-a(x-\tau)}h_1d\tau$$

At this point I don't know if I'm making things any easier. Especially because I have again arrived at $Y(s)=\frac{1-e^{-s}}{s(s+a)}$. I don't know how to place $h_1$ into the equation. I know that I can also write it using the Heaviside function as 
$$1-u_1=1-u(t-1)$$
which gives me
$$\int_0^xe^{-a(x-\tau)}(1-u(\tau-1))d\tau$$

Am I on the right track? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but the inverse transform of $$Y(s) = \frac{1 - e^{-s}}{s(s+a)}$$ isn't too bad. We see $$\frac{1}{s(s+a)} = \frac{1}a \left(\frac 1 s - \frac 1 {s+a} \right)$$ so $$Y(s) =\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac 1 s - \frac 1 {s+a}- \frac {e^{-s}} s + \frac {e^{-s}} {s+a} \right) $$ which gives $$y(t) = \frac{1}{a}\left( 1 -e^{-at}  - u(t-1)(1 - e^{-a(t-1)} )\right)$$ where $u(t)$ is the unit step function: $$u(t) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0, & t < 0, \\ 1 & t \ge 0. \end{matrix} \right.$$ I'd stick with the Laplace transform method.